# Receiving null values when trying to assign a score to a column

Tags: mysql, case, mysql-workbench

I am working on a scoring system in `MySQL Workbench` and for the most part it is going smoothly. One column is giving me trouble and keeps resulting in null values even though the original data contains no null values. This is the query I am using to fetch the column.

```
SELECT 
    (CASE days_in_current_status
        WHEN days_in_current_status < 1000 THEN 0.33 * 20
        WHEN days_in_current_status BETWEEN 1000 and 2000 THEN 0.66 * 20
        WHEN days_in_current_status > 2000 THEN 1 * 20
    END) AS DI_score
FROM
    issues
```

Here is a picture of the values from the original column.

[image: Original values from the data]

Any ideas on what is missing here? I am about to get some sleep and try again tomorrow but any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: What column type is days_in_current_status?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the way you have written your `CASE` expression. In the form that you have written it, it is comparing the value of `days_in_current_status` with the value of `days_in_current_status < 1000` (or one of the other logical expressions), which in MySQL will either be `1 (true)` or `0 (false)`. As a result, none of the branches of the `CASE` will match (unless  `days_in_current_status` happened to be 1 or 0) and since you have no `ELSE` clause, the result is `NULL`. If you rewrite your `CASE` expression as below it should work as expected.

```
(CASE
    WHEN days_in_current_status < 1000 THEN 0.33 * 20
    WHEN days_in_current_status BETWEEN 1000 and 2000 THEN 0.66 * 20
    WHEN days_in_current_status > 2000 THEN 1 * 20
END) AS DI_score
```

See the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) for a discussion of the two forms of the `CASE` expression.

Comment: Hi Hassan, did this not answer your question? If not, can you provide more information to help answer it?